# Proxy server not getting hit through API gateway

Tags: node.js, middleware, http-proxy, proxy-server, http-proxy-middleware

In my code I am using API Gateway and creating proxy-middleware for microservices. The individual microservices are working fine but when I am delegating the requests to these microservices through an API gateway, its not working. The proxies are getting created.

```
const {createProxyMiddleware}  = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use('/authservice',createProxyMiddleware({target:'http://localhost:3001',changeOrigin:true}));

app.use('/flightservice',createProxyMiddleware({target:'http://localhost:3000',changeOrigin:true}));
```

the proxies are created as follows:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:3001
[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:3000
[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:3002
```

I even tried requiring createProxyMiddleware without braces but it didn't work.